# Pigtail solution?

Tags: lighting, fans, multiway-switch

[image]I have a celing fan in one room, a light with three 60 watt bulbs in the kitchen. They are both controlled by switches, but one turns off and the other one turns on. Can I pigtail them together on the same switch? I've identified which wires I need to put together.

Comment: We'd need to see some pictures of the boxes, switches involved.

Comment: The two wires in question are the blue and yellow wires going through the conduit in the top of the switch box

Comment: Am I seeing right that someone used a yellow wire for ground?!

Comment: The wiring I'm seeing doesn't seem to make sense. I see three wires going up (I assume) to the fixtures. One is coming off one switch and two off the other. I don't see a neutral anywhere unless the right-hand switch is switching the neutral. I don't know who wired this but if this is a representative sample of your house wiring, I'd kill the main breaker and not turn it back on until I got an electrician in to check everything.

Comment: @DoxyLover That wire's behind the grounding bracket... stay safe out there. Possibly in a backstab.

Comment: There is a separate neutral running through the condominium, the main line for power I identified the orange as the incoming voltage from the top. The wires on the bottom lead to another three way switch on the other side of the kitchen

Comment: @Mike -- can you post photos of the insides of the other switch boxes involved please?

Comment: What is your location in the world?  I am also wondering if the wiring was modified from original.

Answer (score 1):

> There is a separate neutral running through the condominium,

That's completely illegal.  Nobody is allowed to wire like that.

You can't have a master neutral that everything goes back to!  Right off the bat, it would overload. It would also trip every GFCI and AFCI!

All the related conductors must be grouped together.  So the neutral must come along with the hot(s).

Another way of saying that is that the currents in each of the wires in a cable or conduit must be equal/cancel each other out/etc.

Another way of saying that is current can't flow in a big loop.  It can't go from lamp to switch 1 to switch 2 back to lamp.

Another way of saying that is that cables or conduits must be laid out in a tree topology, i.e. you can have branches but you cannot have pipes looping back to each other.  If wire (or sequence of wires) could exit out one conduit, go through different conduits and reenter the same box from another conduit, that is a loop. You can't have those.

So this whole thing is seriously messed up.

The good news is, this is conduit.  So neutrals or other appropriate wires can simply be added to the pipe as needed.

I find it difficult to believe someone took delivery of a house where a light cannot be turned off.  Are these switch changes your work?

Comment: No, I added some 4 way switches later on. This is what I had to work with, the neutral wires are behind the light fixtures. I saw that when I installed a remote for a ceiling fan. You can turn the lights off. I just was wondering if two can be on at the same time.

Comment: @Mike OK so the neutrals (which are the real problem) were like this before, and you added 4-ways (which are probably fine).  And you just want to make the light work, and don't care about the code violations since they seem only statutory and not a threat.   The problem is, first they are a threat, and second it's *really hard* to try to fix *only part of* bad work.  I mean, it's unfamiliar territory for anyone competent.  They wouldn't know *how*.  So I suggest a more systematic review.

Comment: I'm really not looking forward to ripping out drywall, plus it's a concrete ceiling with conduit buried in it. This was my girlfriend's place, I started to do a little remodeling and found this mess, thanks.

Comment: @Mike fear not the conduit. You won't need to futz with the pipe itself, the scope of the project only includes pulling new wires into the existing pipe.   I had to  fix a whole factory full of bad wire in conduit, was not that bad.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to run separate wires and a breaker for just the kitchen light.